# Train decelerations in no power condition

Tags: friction

Suppose a train is running at 30kmph and suddenly the power is switched off. How do we calculate the reducing velocity at intervals and what factors will affect the change in it?. Further how much time will it take to stop from that position and the distance it will cover before coming to halt?

Comment: So two things come to mind: air resistance and rolling resistance.

Comment: … And slope of the tracks. And sum of forces = m*a.

Comment: If you know either the time or the distance you can work out the other, assuming constant deceleration.